# Form inside fancybox with target="_blank" (webkit)

Tags: forms, fancybox, modal-window

I have a paypal standard button (buy now) created by the paypal wizard that submits to a new window(tab) via `<form target="_new" [...]>`. In IE and Firefox it works ok, but in webkit browsers (like chrome and safari) it doesn't make a new window.

The form is in a modal window created by fancybox. Is it a webkit bug or something messed up in code?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the problem,

On plain fancybox (not 2.0+) if you call `parent.$.fancybox.close()` after calling $("#formID").submit(), it cancels the webkit submission.

One quickndirty solution is to make a 1sec timeout (to wait until the target is opened) then close the fancybox.